windows virtual machine- installation
following this instqllqtion guide
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-a-windows-11-vm-using-lxd#3-create-a-new-vm
step3:
lxc init win11 --vm --empty "Error: LXD unix socket "/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket" not accessible: permission denied"
how to proceed plz ?!

Please [edit] your question and tell us what you have done. Don't just link to the instructions you followed, show us, in the question, what you did, how you adapted those instructions etc. What command gives you this error?

This looks similar to your question of two days ago, but that question has more information.

Did you run as root?  Use sudo at the beginning of your command and type in your user password when asked.
